# Shell Scripting Value Too Great For Base Issue

Tags: bash, shell, hex, md5sum

Good localtime,

The line below is a part of a shell script that performs checks against md5sums for different projects. To the best of my knowledge, this line has worked dozens of times over the last year (comparing thousands of files/jars), but it is throwing a "value too great for base" error now. I did some digging and it seems as if the shell is trying to read those hex md5sums as decimal? I tried forcing hex by using #16 but only ran into other syntax issues. Any thoughts?

```
if [ ${AKVArray[${BJarHash}]} ] || [ ${ArtfArray[${BJarHash}]} ]; then
    echo -e "${GREEN} -- We have a match!: $BJAR ->"| tee -a "$CONSOLE_OUTPUT_FILE"
```

Comment: "Good localtime" is priceless.

Comment: What is the complete error message?

Comment: There's prob. an md5 that consists of just digits.

Comment: Always quote your variable expansions

Comment: "56b6e875717.........: Value too great for base (Error token is "56b6e875717......... ") where the "...." are the rest of the md5sum.

Comment: We just moved this script off a Windows system today, and I do not have dos2unix available currently. Wondering if that is why it is suddenly acting strange.

Comment: Please post a full [MCVE]. Please check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net and fix errors before posting . There is no `md5sum` in the code shown. `I tried forcing hex by using #16 ` where? How exactly? What "other issues"?

Comment: AKVArray and ArtfArray are what Java would call a `Map<Integer, String>`, so the key is being unsuccessfully interpreted as an integer. Since it appears you want to use hex md5 sums as keys, you should switch to a `Map<String, String>` equivalent associative array with `declare -A`